# How do I get the first letter of a captured group?

Tags: regular-expression, substitute

The old three lines:

```
able
bee
must
```

I want to change them to this in vim:

```
able /home/words/a/able
bee /home/words/b/bee
must /home/words/m/must
```

I knew using `%s/^\(.*\)$/\1/home/wprds/\1` can add some characters, but how can I get the first letter of each substitution?

Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: You can find the answer in the fine documentation: Read about at `:h \U` `:h \u` and perhaps also `:h \zs`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure this is exactly what you ask for, but assuming you wanted to replace:

```
able
bee
must
```

… with:

```
able /home/words/a/able
bee /home/words/b/bee
must /home/words/m/must
```

Then, you could try the following substitution command:

```
:%s:\v(.).*:& /home/words/\1/&
```

Which could be broken down like this:

```
%s:\v(.).*:& /home/words/\1/&
"  |  |    | |           |  |
"  |  |    | |           |  +-- old line
"  |  |    | |           +-- first captured character
"  |  |    | +-- `/home/words/` literally
"  |  |    +-- beginning of the replacement: old line
"  |  +-- capture first letter on the line
"  +-- very magic mode
```

Since the replacement part contains slash characters, to avoid having to escape them, this substitution uses a colon (`:`) as a delimiter to separate the name of the command from the pattern, and the pattern from the replacement (instead of a usual slash).

In the replacement part, you can refer to any text that you have captured in the pattern with the first group of parentheses through the expression `\1`. Here the first group of parentheses is used to capture the first character on each line.
And you can refer to the whole pattern with the metacharacter `&` or `\0`.

Answer (score 3):

[User9433424's answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/11435/2920) is a great solution, but you could also do this without any substitute or regex commands.

```
:%norm ywA /home/words/<C-v><esc>pblC/<C-v><esc>"0p
```

Or, if you have other lines in the buffer that you don't want to modify, you could visually select them an do this:

```
:norm ywA /home/words/<C-v><esc>pblC/<C-v><esc>"0p
```

(The same except for the `%`)

This simply applies a set of keystrokes to each line as if you had manually typed them on each line. The `<C-v>` is <kbd>ctrl-v</kbd>, and is needed so that you can insert a literal <kbd>esc</kbd> character into the command.